# Cannot view logged file on PC but can see it on my phone

Tags: android, csv, logging

```
public void appendLog(String text) {
    File logFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Nexus_Uroflow_" + m_Text + ".csv");                                                       // newly changed
    if (!logFile.exists()) {
        try {
            logFile.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error while creating file. ", e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    try {
        // BufferedWriter for performance, true to set append to file flag
        BufferedWriter buf = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(logFile,
                true));
        buf.append(text);
        buf.newLine();
        buf.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

hi guys, i have an app that logs data to csv file. However i have can see it in my phone, but not in my PC until i moved those file to a folder in phone. Can anyone explain to me what is the problem ? Thanks in advance.

[Phone storage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCJoC.png)
[View in PC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QI652.png)

Comment: i think that file hide in pc. press ctrl+h or go to view and tick on show hide.

Comment: Hi, it is not hidden, i tried it. It is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

As Far as I know, `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` folder completely depends on phone. Quote from [reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory()):

> Note: don't be confused by the word "external" here. This directory
>   can better be thought as media/shared storage. It is a filesystem that
>   can hold a relatively large amount of data and that is shared across
>   all applications (does not enforce permissions). Traditionally this is
>   an SD card, but it may also be implemented as built-in storage in a
>   device that is distinct from the protected internal storage and can be
>   mounted as a filesystem on a computer.

It means each phone can consider a specific folder (even on internal memory) as its external storage directory and return it in `getExternalStorageDirectory()`. Maybe on your phone, this folder is not really on where you expect and that's why you cannot find it. At least I had similar problem in one of the famous brands.

I personally use `/sdcard/` folder whenever I want to push something using `adb` to my phone/emulator. In this case I almost always can find it easily. But this is not correct approach if you want to use it for your app.

And finally always use [Context.getExternalStorageDirectory()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String)) rather than `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`.

Comment: Hi there. I appreciate your reply. Do u mind to teach me how to add a folder in this line ? 
 File logFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Nexus_Uroflow_" + m_Text + ".csv");    

i have tried 
 File logFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +  ''/Uroflow'' +"/Nexus_Uroflow_" + m_Text + ".csv");   

not working though